# Which Locale should I specify when I call String#toLowerCase?

Tags: java, localization, internationalization

In Java the `String#toLowerCase` method uses the default system `Locale` to determine how to handle lowercasing. If I am lowercasing some ASCII text and want to be sure that this is processed as expected which Locale should I use?

EDIT: I'm mainly concerned about programming identifiers such as table and column names in a schema. As such I want English lower casing to apply.

`Locale.ROOT` states that it is the *language/country neutral locale for the locale sensitive operations*

`Locale.ENGLISH` would presumably also be a safe choice.

Comment: "some ASCII text": do you really mean ASCII text. Or do you mean "some text"?

Comment: I meant ASCII. I was trying to imply that I wasn't using any non ASCII chars. I have clarified on the question.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, `Locale.ENGLISH` is a safe choice for case operations for things like programming language identifiers and URL parts since it doesn't involve any special casing rules and all 7-bit ASCII characters in the ENGLISH case-convert to 7-bit ASCII characters.

That is not true for all other locales.  In Turkish, the 'I' and 'i' characters are not case-converted to one another.

["Dotted and dotless I"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dotted_and_dotless_I) explains:

> The Turkish alphabet, which is a variant of the Latin alphabet, includes two distinct versions of the letter I, one dotted and the other dotless.
>
> In Unicode, U+0131 is a lower case letter dotless i (ı). U+0130 (İ) is capital i with dot. ISO-8859-9 has them at positions 0xFD and 0xDD respectively. In normal typography, when lower case i is combined with other diacritics, the dot is generally removed before the diacritic is added; however, Unicode still lists the equivalent combining sequences as including the dotted i, since logically it is the normal dotted i character that is being modified.
>
> Most Unicode software uppercases ı to I and lowercases İ to i, but, unless specifically set up for Turkish, it lowercases I to i and uppercases i to I. Thus uppercasing then lowercasing, or vice versa, changes the letters.

The list of special exceptions is maintained at http://unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/SpecialCasing.txt

> ```
> # ================================================================================
>
> # Turkish and Azeri
>
> # I and i-dotless; I-dot and i are case pairs in Turkish and Azeri
> # The following rules handle those cases.
>
> 0130; 0069; 0130; 0130; tr; # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I WITH DOT ABOVE
> 0130; 0069; 0130; 0130; az; # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I WITH DOT ABOVE
>
> # When lowercasing, remove dot_above in the sequence I + dot_above, which will turn into i.
> # This matches the behavior of the canonically equivalent I-dot_above
>
> 0307; ; 0307; 0307; tr After_I; # COMBINING DOT ABOVE
> 0307; ; 0307; 0307; az After_I; # COMBINING DOT ABOVE
> ```
>
> ...

Comment: "That is not true for all other locales", which can not use ASCII.

Comment: In what circumstances would you use the ROOT locale? I have been using that to mean that I don't want to have any special case case-folding applied.

Comment: @Raedwald, I'm not sure I understand.  Could you please expand on your comment?

Comment: @mchr, I believe `Locale.ROOT` is similar to `LANG=C` in shell environments.  It specifies that collation is lexicographic, that no special case conditions apply, and that number formatting is close to that produced by `String.valueOf(number)`.

Comment: A DecimalFormat created with Locale.ROOT still uses grouping characters, which differs from `String.valueOf`. Otherwise I think Locale.ROOT might make it more clear that the value is used internally and not for display purposes.

Comment: @JörnHorstmann, Good to know.  Does it reliably use '.' only to mean integer/fraction separator?

Comment: @MikeSamuel: I think it does, but I'm still searching if there are any differences to `Locale.ENGLISH`.

Comment: "That is not true for all other locales", which can not use ASCII: ASCII is an encoding that can not encode non-English Unicode code points. Therefore if some text is described as "ASCII" this means it is in English.

Comment: @Raedwald, "ASCII" is the name of an encoding, but it also refers to a particular unicode [code-page](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0000.pdf).  Locales for writing systems that do not use Roman characters do case-fold ASCII characters to ASCII characters since they do not include any special case conversion rules that involve ASCII codepoints.

Comment: @JörnHorstmann did you ever figure out the differences between `Locale.ROOT` and `Locale.ENGLISH`?

Comment: @mirabilos Are you wondering what `NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.ROOT)` does?  If so, I get `#,##0.###` which, as @jörn-horstmann points out has a digit group separator.

Comment: @MikeSamuel I was more wondering whether I should use ENGLISH or ROOT for things like lowercasing, but also the differences between these two in general. The source code is… on a different abstraction level.

Comment: @mirabilos I believe case adjustments are the same.  As pointed out in the answer, there are no special casing rules for *en*.  For case adjustments of human language terms, you should use the user's locale though.  For case adjustments of machine identifiers, maybe use [UAX-31](https://unicode.org/reports/tr31/#normalization_and_case).

Comment: I should probably use Locale.ROOT for when I compare file names by lowercasing them (or checking if they are in a HashSet, for example), right ?

Comment: @androiddeveloper That sounds best.

Comment: @MikeSamuel OK thanks

Answer (score 3):

> If I am lowercasing some ASCII text and want to be sure that this is processed as expected which Locale should I use?

That depends on what "as expected" means for you. The point of allowing to specify a Locale is that uppercaseing/lowercasing does not work the same in all languages, even though they may use the same letters. So specify the Locale you and/or your customers live in, and it will probably work as you/they expect.

Comment: The OP says "some ASCII text". As ASCII is useful for only English text, "as expected" must mean as expected in English.

Comment: @Raedwald, why English? Latin letters are used in several different languages, not only european. If you use diacritic letters from ASCII, a scope of languages is wider.

Comment: @CoolMind ASCII does not have *any* diacritic letters. You are probably confusing ASCII with one of the several 8-bit character sets that extend ASCII to provide diacritics and additional European letters.

Comment: @Raedwald, sorry, agree with you. Most Latin-based languages have more than 26 letters.