# how to use toUppercase(locale) in android 4.2?

Tags: android

[image]Im using android 4.2 SDK,  I have been getting a warning on this line of code:

```
String text0 = tagalogText.getText().toString();
String textA = text0.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + text0.substring(1).toLowerCase();
```

When I hover over it, it says:

```
Implicitly using the default locale is a common source of bugs: Use toUpperCase(Locale) instead.
```

and

Implicitly using the default locale is a common source of bugs: Use toLowerCase(Locale) instead.

I copy the code from Java, not in Java for android.
Does anyone know how to remove this error? And why is it now a preferred way to use this method?

Comment: did you checked this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11063102/using-locales-with-javas-tolowercase-and-touppercase and this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13444546/android-adt-21-0-warning-implicitly-using-the-default-locale

Answer (score 5):

Just need to **clean project**.

I had same trouble.  I wasn't relying on the default locale, and explicitly tried Locale.US, and Locale.English, yet still got the yellow lint warning.  Went away after cleaning.

```
string.toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a lint *warning*, not an error. The reason is that the default locale should be used for *user-facing* data - if you're rendering something that the user may prefer to see in a style/format specific to their locality.

You need to decide whether it's appropriate to use the default locale:

- if this is a string that will be used behind the scenes *and* your architecture expects this string to be uniform across all devices across the world, then you should specify a locale explicitly - usually Locale.US
- if it's a user-facing string *or* your architecture doesn't care if it's different on other devices (i.e. it's only used internally, and isn't expected to be in a particular format other than the specified case), then you can safely ignore the lint warning.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved it:

```
string.toUpperCase(getResources().getConfiguration().locale));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
text0.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

From doc [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html)

> A common mistake is to implicitly use the default locale when
>   producing output meant to be machine-readable. This tends to work on
>   the developer's test devices (especially because so many developers
>   use en_US), but fails when run on a device whose user is in a more
>   complex locale.
>
> For example, if you're formatting integers some locales will use
>   non-ASCII decimal digits. As another example, if you're formatting
>   floating-point numbers some locales will use ',' as the decimal point
>   and '.' for digit grouping. That's correct for human-readable output,
>   but likely to cause problems if presented to another computer
>   (parseDouble(String) can't parse such a number, for example). You
>   should also be wary of the toLowerCase() and toUpperCase() overloads
>   that don't take a Locale: in Turkey, for example, the characters 'i'
>   and 'I' won't be converted to 'I' and 'i'. This is the correct
>   behavior for Turkish text (such as user input), but inappropriate for,
>   say, HTTP headers.

Comment: This has the same problems the warning implies, namely that the default locale can introduce bugs.

Comment: Your post originally said Locale.getDefault(), hence my comment.

Comment: Yes ,, I just edited this .. after reading the doc... sorry for the ambiguous edit

Comment: I used what you said but when i try to hover it again..the same statement above is still there.

Answer (score 0):

It means there can be language problems with relying on the default Locale, which varies between systems. Use this instead:

```
text0.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase(Locale.US);
```

Comment: Does it usually happen in android?

Comment: It's not an Android specific problem.

Comment: Well, actually i copied the code from java in PC based and it is really different when i adapt the code to android. I just wondering why does the code from the PC based did not use toUpperCase(Locale.US);?

Comment: It's not an error, it's just a potential source of bugs, so Android added a warning about it.

Comment: H @lesleh. Im just new here in android.. I tried your code but the warning is still there.. what should i do? Pls help me..

Comment: That's strange, the code I posted should have fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't indicate that you got an answer, so try this (something similar worked for me):

```
text0 = text0.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();
text1 = text0.substring(1).toLowerCase();
String textA = text0 + text1;
```

It's seems as though the assignment is critical.

Let me know if it works.

Take care.

Comment: Hi i tried to use your code but it still didnt work to me. can i have ung fb account so i can contact you about this..

Comment: I'm so sorry for not getting back to you sooner. Actually, I just saw this since I don't log in regularly. I don't have a fb account. but I'm surprise the assignment didn't work. If the message you see is just a warning, I'd ignore it and move on. Take care.