# Problem with letters "I,İ" when I convert them to lowercase

Tags: java

For example when i printing:

```
System.out.println("I".toLowerCase()+ "İ".toLowerCase())
```

I get this:

```
i i̇
```

Well, they are not the same, but there is a problem, the lowercase of these letters `I İ` is - `ı i`.

How to get the same letters? with no dot?

Comment: You may want to look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10336730/which-locale-should-i-specify-when-i-call-string-tolowercase

Comment: It depends on the font you are using....

Comment: The lowercase of a letter is Locale dependant (there is a reason why [.toLowerCase accepts a locale as an argument](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toLowerCase(java.util.Locale))). In most latin-alphabet languages (French, Spanish, ... but also English or German), the lowercase of `I` is `i`, with a dot. In turkish, the dotted and non dotted `I` (upper or lower case) are *entirely different* letters. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dotted_and_dotless_I . So... what is your goal ?

Comment: this I is latin, so you need to convert it.

Comment: What locale are you using in your program? You can set the default locale like this: `Locale.setDefault(new Locale("pt", "BR"));`. You can also provide a locale in the call to `toLowerCase`. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809098/how-do-i-set-the-default-locale-in-the-jvm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Normally" (read: in almost all locales) the lower-case of `I` (Unicode character [U+0049 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0049/index.htm), ASCII 73) is `i` (Unicode character [U+0069 LATIN SMALL LETTER I](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0069/index.htm), ASCII 105).

In some locales (as far as I know only Turkish and Azerbaijan locales) the lower-case of U+0049 I is [U+0131 LATIN SMALL LETTER DOTLESS I](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0131/index.htm).

So *neither* answer is technically right or wrong in all cases.

To get the desired result, you need to specify the intended locale to [the `toLowerCase` method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#toLowerCase(java.util.Locale)):

```
String turkishLowerCase = "I".toLowerCase(Locale.forLanguageTag("tr-TR");
String englishLowerCase = "I".toLowerCase(Locale.forLanguageTag("en-US");
```

`turkishLowerCase` will be `ı` and `englishLowerCase` will be `i`.

Answer (score -1):

With the latin alphabet the Letter "I" is "i" in lowercase.

You can use a localized version of `toLowerCase` to resolve your issue.

```java
System.out.println("I".toLocaleLowerCase()+ "İ".toLocaleLowerCase());
```

If that doesn't help you, you should replace them manually:

```java
System.out.println("I".replaceAll("I", "ı")+ "İ".replaceAll("İ", "i"));
```